# PHP7 with PHPStorm 10

Tags: php, phpstorm, php-7

I met some problems while testing new PHP 7 with PHPStorm 10. Is it a bug?

File1.php

```
    namespace Game\Fields;


abstract class Field
{
    protected $resources = [];

    protected $requirements = [];

    protected $destruction;

    public function __construct (array $resources, array $requirements, int $destruction)
    {
        $this->resources = $resources;
        $this->requirements = $requirements;
        $this->destruction = $destruction;
    }

    public function getResources (): array
    {
        return $this->resources;
    }

    public function getRequirements (): int
    {
        return $this->requirements;
    }

    public function getDestruction (): int
    {
        return $this->destruction;
    }
}

class DeepDeath extends Field {}

class MysteryDark extends Field {}

class SunEnd extends Field {}
```

File2.php

```
declare(strict_types=1);

require_once __DIR__ . '/Fields/Fields.php';

$level = new \Game\Fields\DeepDeath([], [], 30);

echo($level->getDestruction());
```

In browser everything is OK but PHPStorm give me errors (visible in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxiT3.png)).

[image]

I think that it is a bug. Is there any way to solve this problem? I tried to use EAP from this [Site](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program) but it didn't solve problem.

Comment: Did you changed the PHP settings of your project ? To enable PHP 7 ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, will changing your constructor signature to use `\int $destruction` prevent the error?

Comment: @Don't Panic : I don't think this would work as int is a forbidden class name in php 7 so it would'nt be a namespace issue

Comment: I was just guessing, but I googled around a bit and found [this discussion](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=internals@lists.php.net&q=subject:%22Re\%3A+\[PHP\-DEV\]+Re\%3A+Scalar+Type+Declaration+Syntax+Weirdness%22&o=newest&f=1) that appears to be about this issue.

Answer (score 3):

To enable PHP 7 in PHP Storm, go to

Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP

And change the PHP language level to "7" in the development environment section.

Comment: Unfortunately interpreter is set to PHP 7 and version of PHP is set to 7 :(